# emacs, call a kbd macro in defun function

Tags: emacs, elisp

I defined a sequence of keys into a macro and insert it to my .emacs as something like:

```
(fset 'xxx [keys])
```

Is there a way to call the kbd macro xxx in a defun function? 
I tried to call it just as regular function, but it has an error "definition of xxx is void"

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1:

```
(execute-kbd-macro 'foo)
```

Option 2...

There are two ways to generate code for a macro:

`name-last-kbd-macro` and `kmacro-name-last-macro`

The former tends to generate code like you've shown.

The latter, which is conveniently bound to <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>, generates a *lambda form* for the macro -- i.e. a function -- which means that you can call it in code.

So:

- Define macro.
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> `foo` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- You can now use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `foo`
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `insert-kbd-macro` <kbd>RET</kbd> `foo` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- You can now write code which calls `(foo)`.

Comment: thanks you, I think it should be (execute-kbd-macro (symbol-function 'foo))

Comment: That's not necessary. If the argument is a symbol, `execute-kbd-macro` uses its function slot (as documented).

Answer (score 0):

The way to run a command from Elisp is to call `execute-command`.  That works for interactive functions as well as for keyboard macros.